# TextField autoSize+italics cuts of last character

Tags: actionscript-3, textfield

In actionscript 3,  my `TextField` has :

- CSS styling
- embedded fonts
- textAlign : CENTER
- autoSize : CENTER

... when italics are used the very right character gets slightly cut off (specially caps).
It basically seems that it fails detecting the right size.

I've had this problem before but just wondered is there a nice workaround (instead of checking `textWidth` or offsetting text etc.)?

Comment: I mostly found that there are no "pretty" solutions to all Flash's problems with displaying text properly. I think I found a whitespace character before to fix the problem. Or you could do as you say and just check the width yourself.

Answer (score 3):

Initialize your `textField` as you always do, using multiline, autosize, htmlText...

Then do this little trick :

```
// saving wanted width and height plus 1px to get some space for last char
var savedWidth = myTextField.width + 1;
var savedHeight = myTextField.height + 1;

// removing autoSize, wich is the origin of the problem i think                 
myTextField.autoSize = "none";      

// now manually autoSizing the textField with saved values          
myTextField.width = savedWidth;
myTextField.height = savedHeight;
```

Answer (score 1):

Not that it is much comfort to you, but Flash sometimes has trouble with this seemingly simple task. CSS styling of html `TextField` was a nice addition but it has caused headaches for text-rendering. In fact I *very* rarely use CSS for styling text for that reason. I can only imagine that combining **bold**, *italic* and normal type faces within the HTML causes Flash to get some of the width calculations wrong which causes `autoSize` to set the mask a tiny bit short. I hope very much that the [new text rendering engine in Flash Player 10](http://www.insideria.com/2009/03/flash-text-engine.html) will finally fix these issues (it certainly looks better in theory).

So *my* solution is *never* to use HTML with the exception being when I require `<a>` links in my text ... and there are even some tricky text shifting issues there. In those cases I avoid mixing different font weights and font styles within the same text field. All other cases I use `TextFormat` directly on `TextField`.

I suppose if you can't get out of your current architecture (for some reason) you could try adding `&nbsp;` to the end of your html encoded strings. Or you could manually set the width of the field and not rely on `autoSize` (as you have mentioned). But if you keep on the CSS/HTML route you may find another new and painful limitation just when you don't want it.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the FTE. Something to look into for sure. TextFields are currently a total pain in my ass and I'm glad that there's an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

I've had issues with `TextField` masks behaving differently in the Flash preview, and in the actual browser plugin. Usually, and this is strange to me, it would appear more correctly in the browser. Have you tried running the `swf` in a browser to see if the problem is actually an annoyance rather than a permanent problem?

I had said this:
My in-ideal approach to solving this is to attach a change event to the `TextField` which always adds a space after the last character of the field. And then to remember to trim this space off when using the value.

But that didn't take into account that this probably doesn't have a change event and that it's an HTML rendered text field. To add a trailing space in the HTML text field throw in an `&nbsp;` again, that's not really fixing the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your input. It's not an input fields though. Adding spaces doesn't work since white spaces are trimmed if the textField is used with HTML.