# TextField htmlText+italics cuts of last character

Tags: actionscript-3, textfield

htmlText + italic – the last character cuts off

Below is the similar problem, but I don’t use autosize [TextField autoSize+italics cuts of last character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1516391/textfield-autosizeitalics-cuts-of-last-character)

Are there any other variants how to solve this problem?
The problematic text is on the screenshot: http://finmarkets.org/images/problem.jpg

Comment: I'd say the root of this problem is with the font, giving Flash a hard time calculating the correct width of the characters. Are  you using embedded fonts? I've seen this a few times when using device fonts so if you aren't embedding the font, you should try that. If you are, are you embedding the italic version of the font as well?

Comment: In the efforts to embed fonts is not possible

Answer (score 1):

you should try to add some pixels to your textfield's width after having feed it with its content : `yourTextField.width += 3;`

Comment: If you look at the supplied screen shot, you'll see that the problem occurs inline where the last italic character meets the last, non-italic closing parenthesis.

Comment: It does not help.
Field width is increased, but the text is cut off