# Why does second line of text vanish when stage is being re-sized ActionScript 3?

Tags: actionscript-3, air, flash-builder

I have this code. It creates two lines of text on the stage but when ever the stage get re-sized the second line of text can vanish when the stage is being scaled. Does anyone know why this is happening? Thank you for your help in advance!

```
var text:TextField=new TextField();
var textFormat:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
textFormat.color=0x000000;
textFormat.size=45;
textFormat.bold=true;
textFormat.font="Impact";
textFormat.italic=true;
text.x=8;
text.y=5;
text.width=200;
text.text = "Line One\nLine two";
text.setTextFormat(textFormat);
text.height=text.textHeight +4;
sprite.addChild(text);
```

The sprite is then added to the stage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code :

```
var text:TextField=new TextField();
var textFormat:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
textFormat.color=0x000000;
textFormat.size=45;
textFormat.bold=true;
textFormat.font="Impact";
textFormat.italic=true;
text.x = 8;
text.border = true;
text.y=5;
text.width=200;
text.text = "Line One\nLine two";
text.setTextFormat(textFormat);
text.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
sprite.addChild(text);
```

Notice the addition of the auto size, that seems to fix your problem.

Comment: so its working but is cutting of the end unless i remove italics odd Thanks for your help! I don't know about that.

Comment: Check out this question and answers : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1516391/textfield-autosizeitalics-cuts-of-last-character

Adding a whitespace after the lines helps there are other solutions too but mostly hack jobs.